# Why did Biggles die?

Tags: plot-explanation, american-sniper

In *American Sniper*, Biggles who got shot in the face by a bullet that reflected from his rifle, before his death, was seen as Chris Kyle visits him. He looked in good condition. He was talking about how doctors will fix his face. He wasn't even in intensive care. But then it has been told that he died without any further explanation.

Is there any information about his death in the book?

Am I misjudging the scene thinking he actually wasn't still in critical condition while he was?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is the movie doesn't reflect real life events in this case. Rather than die shortly after the incident as depicted by the movie, Ryan Job was actually discharged from the Navy, got married, and passed away over two years later due to complications from facial reconstructive surgery. This is mentioned in multiple articles comparing the movie to the book/real life.

From [here](http://www.historyvshollywood.com/reelfaces/american-sniper/):

> **Did Ryan "Biggles" Job only survive for a short while after being blinded by a bullet?**
>
> No. In the movie, Ryan "Biggles" Job (Jake
> McDorman) is blinded by Syrian sniper Mustafa. He survives for a short
> period of time and proposes to his girlfriend while in the hospital.
> Kyle visits him shortly before leaving for his fourth tour and learns
> of Ryan's death just after he arrives back in Iraq.
>
> In real life, Ryan was blinded in battle in 2006 when an enemy
> sniper's bullet struck his rifle, sending pieces of the shattered
> weapon through his face. He survived much longer than he does in the
> movie. He was discharged from the military, got married, attended
> college, got a job, climbed Mount Rainier and Mount Hood, etc. He died
> in 2009 from complications after going back for more facial
> reconstructive surgery while his wife was pregnant with their first
> child

Also [here](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2015/01/23/american_sniper_fact_vs_fiction_how_accurate_is_the_chris_kyle_movie.html):

> In the movie, Ryan Job (or “Biggles,” played by Jake McDorman) is shot
> in the head and blinded by Syrian sniper Mustafa but survives long
> enough to propose to his girlfriend. He dies soon after, and that
> death defines Kyle’s fourth tour in Iraq and spurs him to seek revenge
> against Mustafa. In reality, according to Kyle’s memoir, the Navy
> discharged Biggles from service following his injury. The ex-SEAL
> attended college, began a career, and got married before dying
> following facial reconstruction surgery while his wife was pregnant
> with their first child.

An obituary piece for Ryan Job can be found [here](http://seattletimes.com/html/obituaries/2009945844_ryanjob26m.html), highlighting his many accomplishments after his discharge from the Navy.

Comment: Well explained.